# Multiple jss in components when using react-planet which override other components' styles

Tags: react-hooks, material-ui, jss

I added the `<Planet/>` (from react-planet) to my App and the placement of some `<Grid/>` (from the Material UI) components changed.

While looking inside "Elements" in DevTool I noticed that divs inside the `<Planet/>` component have two classes `jss3` and `jss{i}` where `i` is the next integral number. Each has different properties inside which overwrites every component in App that is using one of the `jss{i}` classes.

I also noticed that at first render `i` iteration, which applies to `jss{i}` used in newly created divs, starts from 1 and ends at 9 - because I have 6 planets so 1 for the main div, 2 for the central planet, 3 for divs' first class, and 4-9 for the six divs' second class. After the second render number goes from 10 to 18.

Screenshots of Elements at [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL4bq.png) render and [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg0sb.png).

[The `class ={jss3 jss4}` example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoMLq.png)

[The `class ={jss3 jss5}` example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFwiu.png)

I assume that after creating planets by `<Planet/>`, whose children have two classes, the newly created class `jss{i}`, based on `makeStyles-root-{i}`, is overwriting properties of `jss{i}`, which is used somewhere else on page by `<Grid/>` components thus changing placement for the whole page.

Code where `<Planet/>` component is used:

```
return (
    <Grid
      item
      container
      justifyContent = "center"
      style = {{ margin: 30 }}
    >
      <Planet
        centerContent={
          <Fab size="small" color="primary" aria-label="add" onClick={handleOpen}>
            <AddIcon />
          </Fab>
        }
        open={isOpen}
        autoClose
        orbitRadius= {50}
        rotation = {90}
        hideOrbit
        friction = {20}
      >
        <div/>
        <div/>
        <div/>
        <Fab size="small" color="primary" aria-label="addBarIcon" onClick={handleChartAddLineChart}>
          <ShowChartIcon />
        </Fab>
        <Fab size="small" color="primary" aria-label="addBarIcon" onClick={handleChartAddBarChart}>
          <BarChartIcon />
        </Fab>
        <Fab size="small" color="primary" aria-label="addBarIcon" onClick={handleChartAddPieChart}>
          <PieChartIcon />
        </Fab>
      </Planet>
    </Grid>
  );
```

I tried putting only `<div/>` components inside `<Planet/>` but nothing changed. Changing from `<Grid/>`  to normal `<div/>`, also didn't change anything.
Also, I tried to find a similar problem on StackOverflow or somewhere else but I am not sure how to describe the problem using proper keywords.

I am not sure if it is some bug in the `react-planet` library that makes `react-planet` and `material-ui` impossible to use together or if there is a problem inside my code.

Comment: I'm speculating this is similar to what they're talking about in this thread: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11843 You may need to use this comment, in particular: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11843#issuecomment-534982194

Comment: I tried to implement a suggested solution and it came out even worse, for example: class="c1 c2 c29 c3 c19", but thanks to your comment now I know where to search for answers. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what was exactly the cause of the "multiply class in one component" bug, but I copied [Planet.tsx and Orbit.tsx](https://github.com/innFactory/react-planet/tree/master/src/components) from the react-planet repository and changed some code, get rid of makeStyles and problem solved. It was probably of nested makeStyles in all of those components in react-planet which conflicted with each other at different component rendering levels causing it to render multiple times in one object.

Additionally, it was overriding Material UI components styles due to simplified class naming from MUI makeStyle to css class while building production (makeStyles-root-{i} -> jss{i}, makeStyles -> jss).

Overriding styles were probably caused by the react-planets dependency of the old/different MUI version than I have for the rest of the code which created two styles generators for each of those versions as mentioned in [MUI FAQ](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/faq/#how-to-fix-a-class-names-production-build-conflict-). The first generator created class from makeStyle for all of my page naming every class jss{i++} for i starting at i=1 and ending when all classes are renamed, then the react-planet generator created styles for its objects naming every class jss{i++} starting from i=1 leading to overriding every previous class=jss{i} with new properties.